# Is it ok to edit an incomplete answer before accepting it?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, etiquette, editing, accepted-answer

I recently posted [a question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/98863/63414) on PSE which only answer is quite good but a little bit incomplete.

You can see by yourself that the user who answered did almost all the passages right but there is still something missing. Being the author of the question, that "something" is an important part to me, so I wrote a comment to invite the user to improve the answer.

I don't know why but they are explaining the missing part the comments without editing the answer. I really want to accept their answer and I would do it if they included the missing part in it.

> Is it ok to edit an answer to make it "acceptable" in the case that:
>
> - the answer is almost complete?
> - the original author is not doing it themselves?
> - the original author is not reading/replying to the comments? (this is not my case but it could happen).

The main reason because I hadn't already do it is that I know that is very important to respect the original author's intentions. Maybe they aren't able to "fill the gap" or maybe they think that the missing part is too simple and it is not worth mentioning it. I don't want pass off my own answer as if it was written by them.

What to do in these cases?

Comment: This is relevant here, I believe Rand's answer could answer most or all of the questions here :) - https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3073/as-op-editing-helping-the-correct-answer?rq=1

Comment: @beastly-gerbil this question is a duplicate of the linked one, thank you